# Is "Maps and Location (New!)" missing in the setup of Developer Orgs?

Tags: setup, geolocation, spring15, feature-activation

In Production- and Sandbox-Orgs (on EU0) there is a menu-entry in the setup called Maps and Location (New!)

It is located between "Tab Names and Labels" and "Home"

[image]

As an unfortunate this menu entry is missing in all of my Developer Orgs (on EU5). Any idea why and how to get it showing in DEs?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As rao said this feature is not enabled in DEs. Unfortunately it also can't be enabled by the support. But you can access parts of it with a workaround even in DEs.

Here is what you'll get from the support:

> As discussed over the phone I informed you that unfortunately there is
>   no way where we can enable the Maps & locations in developer edition,
>   we also uses developer edition and as per standard salesforce edition
>   limitation we also don't have the access for Maps & locations and
>   there is no way where we can activate this for Dev edition.
>
> I apologize as I couldn’t provide you with a resolution to this issue
>   because it is not yet supported by the salesforce edition. So I am
>   closing this case with your permission.

This is very sad, since it looks like something developer-relevant when you read it's description:

> "Maps and Location services uses Google Maps to display maps on
>   standard address fields, **enable creation of Visualforce maps**, and
>   helps users enter new addresses with autocomplete."

What I can't understand is why this feature is disabled in DE. However looking closer to what is covered by the feature, it consists of two parts:

A) on Desktop you get maps below standard address fields.

B) in the Salesforce1 mobile app you get auto-completions and features for the text-fields - which you don't get for the desktop right now.

If you focus on A) you might replicate the feature with some custom javascript, jquery and an iframe. Either you can hack it into the standard UI via js-injections or you can use it in your custom vf pages.

Therfore you can use the URL like this:

```
https://eu5.salesforce.com/maps/SourceBuilder?center=miquell+allee+100%2CFrankfurt%2C%2CDE&zoom=15&size=400x168&markers=color%3Ared|miquell+allee+100%2CFrankfurt%2C%2CDE&language=en_US&src=aloha
```

You have to replace `eu5` by your instance. After the `?` the `center=` controlls the center of your map. It consists of street, city, zip-code, country separated by `%2C`. Spaces needs to be replaced by `+`. With `zoom=` you control the zoom level and with `markers=` you can add colored markers into the map with the same syntax as `center=`.

This perfectly works in developer-editions, too.

Comment: Is this the URL parameter passing method used in the sandbox and production orgs in which maps are successfully enabled. This works and seemingly the functionality is available to dev org users too! Great tip  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As per the official docs maps and locations are not enabled for developer orgs.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_maps.htm

Maps and Location Services | Salesforce
Maps and Location Services

> Available in: **Professional, Enterprise, Performance, and Unlimited
>   editions**.

Answer (score 0):

I guess i faced the same problem with Lightning component. And i was told that the functionality are added to servers after some interval of time. And you will get that feature in some time.